# Stopping page from refreshing when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm trying to write some code that takes an input, but I'm having trouble because when the form is submitted the page refreshes.

This is my code:

```
const changeColour = () => {
  console.log("Submitted");
  const colourForm = document.getElementById("testForm");
  const newColour = colourForm.querySelector("input").value;
  console.log(newFinish);
};

const newForm = vehicle.querySelector(".vehicle-colour");
newForm.addEventListener("submit", changeFinish);
```

In the console log I get `Submitted` and the value of `newColour`, which is my desired output, but it's only there for a split second and then the page refreshes. I'm not too sure how to prevent the page from refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `.preventDefault` method of the event fired should stop the page from submitting.

change

```js
newForm.addEventListener("submit", changeFinish);
```

to

```js
newForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  changeFinish(event);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

changeFinish must be a function with "event" as argument.

```
const changeFinish = event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   /* code here */
}
```